# Deferredで括った関数の完了を待ってある動作を達成したい。

Tags: jquery

問い合わせ内容をよりシンプルにさせて頂きました。
関数：costGetは引数付きで動作する内容ですが、こちらの完了を検知して、その後の動作を達成したい場合、どういったこの関数の呼出し方を行えばよろしいのでしょうか？
https://qiita.com/opengl-8080/items/6eba7922be168edfc439
を参考にして、現在までに仕上げているコーディングは以下のとおりです。
関数本筋の動作とあわせ、Defferedオブジェクトのresolve（reject）メソッドをキックするようなコーディングはどういう記述になるのでしょうか？
適応能力がなく低レベルのことを問い合わせてしまい申し訳ありませんが、何卒よろしくお願い申し上げます。

```
//品名ＣＤ枠の入力と数量枠が１以上の入力で原価を表示。
if (cd != "" && $(this).val() != "") {
    $(".iabtn").prop("disabled", true);     //確認ボタン無効化

    var d = new $.Deferred();

    costGet(maker_val, $obj, text, label); 

    d.promise()
    .then(function() {
        $(".iabtn").prop("disabled", false);    //確認ボタン有効化
        return false;
    });
}

//原価情報の取得
function costGet (cd, $obj, text, label) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "cdcostget.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            maker_no: cd,
            maker_no2 : costGetYM()
        }
    })
    .done(function(data){
        if (data.length <= 0) {
            //いろいろ
        } else {
            //いろいろ
        }
    })
    //サーバ接続エラー
    .fail(function(data){
            //いろいろ
    })

    return 【必要か否か、どういう記述が適策かわからない】;

}
```

Comment: d.always()は、.resolve(): done  .reject():fail どちらの時も呼ばれるのですが、$.ajax().done(function(data){処理})　の中で正常にデータ受信し表示が完了したらボタンの活性処理すれば良いのでは？

Comment: @yyz いつも大変御世話になっております、ご見解を頂き感謝を申し上げます。
.done(function(data){　の中の
downtotalCalc();とdp_a.resolve();の間に一先ず$(".iabtn").prop("disabled", false);を挿入してみましたが
状況は変わっていません。数量枠入力後すぐさま確認ボタンが押下できてしまう、ということです。

ボタンの押下可能な状況が、単価・金額の表示が改まっていない状況下で作り出されていると推察されます。
当初は現在ご提案頂いたようにdoneの中で、ボタン活性化の動作を単純に達成していたのですが
動作がコーディングの順序どおりにならなかったのでDeferredの利用を思いつき挑戦しております。